# Identity Server resource to resource authorize using client credentials and also pass User Identity claims to the second resource

Tags: identityserver4

I have a scenario where

1. User logs accesses a resource (API Resource 1) using Authorization Code flow
2. (API Resource 1) in turn has to access the data from API Resource 2. The resource to resource authorization uses Client Credentials flow and I need to pass the user identity claims to the API Resource 2 while using the Client Credentials flow.

The API Resource 2 also has support for the Authorization Code flow.

Is it possible to do it in this way? Or am I looking at this differently?

Additional Information

- Both the client applications share the same Identity Provider. So, the tokens for both the client applications have same format.

[image]

Comment: What does 'Interactive User Flow' mean on the arrows going between the 'Client Application's and the 'API Resource X's? Is the Client Application passing in the user's access token to the API Resource or is the API Resource the Identity Server? Do both Client Applications share idps? Do the tokens for these client applications have similar claims within them? I think to get a good answer for this, those questions need to be answered

Comment: @Randy, **the Client Application passes** the **user's access token** to **the API Resource**. API Resources are not Identity Server and both the client share the same IdP so, they have same claim types.

As for the arrow between the Client Application and API Resource, the client uses authorization code flow to get the user's access token and calls the API Resource thereafter.

Here, the API Resource 1 also acts as a client and uses it's own access token to get the data from API Resource 2. In this process, I need to pass the user claims so that user claims can be used in API Resource 2.

Comment: Is API Resource 1 getting the same information from API Resource 2 as the Client Application? If so, API Resource 1 can just pass the user access token alone to the endpoints that the Client Application is using. If API Resource 1 needs information/to perform an operation that the Client Application can't, then I see why the token granted from the client_credentials grant type is needed. In that case, I'd recommend just parsing the claims in the token given to API Resource 1 and passing the relevant claim values as a standard json payload (if that's what your api uses) to your API Resource 2.